# How to get object by id in the JSON format using angularfire2?

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

I am looking for simply fetching an object as a JSON, **not** as an observable.

So far I could:

```
fbGetCarById(car_id: string){

        var car_json;

        var car_obs: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
        car_obs =  this.db.object('/cars/'+car_id, { preserveSnapshot: true });

        car_obs.subscribe(snapshot => {
          console.log(snapshot.val())
          car_json = snapshot.val();
        });

        return car_json;
    }
```

However, `.subscribe` is an async function which does not return the snapshot linearly, so everything ends a mess =/.

How can I simply look for an object and have a **simple** JSON object as a response?

Answer (score 0):

You could return a Promise.

```
fbGetCarById(car_id: string):Promise<string>{

    const promise = new Promise<string>((resolve,reject)=>{
    var car_obs: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
    car_obs =  this.db.object('/cars/'+car_id, { preserveSnapshot: true });

    car_obs.subscribe(snapshot => {
      resolve(snapshot.value())
    });

    }


    return promise;
}
```